# Array of form fields

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, jform

I am trying to load a array of form fields as below.

grade.xml

```
<field  name="gralev_code[]" 
  type="text" 
  class="width20"
  label="JSCH_GRALEV_CODE"
/>
```

default.php

```
$this->form->getInput('gralev_code[]')
$this->form->getInput('gralev_code[]')
$this->form->getInput('gralev_code[]')
```

The above shows 3 text fields in the form however the values are not received in the model.

Not sure whether this is achievable or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I manged to get a solution as below.

```
<field  name="gralev_code][]" 
  type="text" 
  class="width20"
  label="JSCH_GRALEV_CODE"
/>
```

in model.php

```
$formdata = $this->_jinput->get('jform', '', 'array');
$vals = $formdata['gralev_code'];
```

On higher Joomla versions from 3.4 use the below

```
gralev_code][
```

Comment: On Joomla 3.4.5 you have to write `name="gralev_code][" `.

Comment: @Laoneo I have tried this, but it doesn't save the plugin's params.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  wrapper, unfortunately you can't fill non unique array keys. Then catch data by "fields" name  ...->input->get('jform')

$jform['keyname']['a1']

```
<fields name="keyname"> 
    <field  name="gralev_code[a1]" 
        type="text" 
        label="JSCH_GRALEV_CODE"/>
 <fields>
```

Comment: Please do your best to use proper English (`you` instead of `u`), format your inline code expressions by wrapping in backticks, and try to keep code indentation to a minimum for less horizontal scrolling.  When you produce excellent posts, then no one needs to touch your work to bring up the quality of the delivery.